# C++ Structured bindings question regarding unordered_map

Tags: c++

I am learning new C++17 features and I came across this:

```
std::vector<int> nums = { 1, 1, 2, 3 };
std::unordered_map<int, size_t> m;
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
{
    const auto& [inserted_entry, inserted_happen] = m.emplace(nums[i], i);
    std::cout << inserted_happen << "\n";
}
```

The result is:

```
1
0
1
1
```

What is happening here? I do not understand.

Also what is inserted_entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`emplace` returns a pair of an iterator to inserted element(or already present element) and a `bool` representing if the insert was successful.

`inserted_happen` is a `bool`.

The second insert fails since `1` already exists as key in the map.

Comment: ahh I see so emplace has a boolean embedded into the function?

Answer (score 2):

[`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) returns `std::pair<iterator, bool>` which then gets "destructured" and 2 bindings get created. `inserted_entry` is a reference to the iterator part and  `inserted_happen` is a reference to the bool part.

Answer (score 2):

Return value of `emplace` is a pair.

The first element of the pair is the iterator for the newly inserted element (if insertion was successful) or of an existing element (if insertion failed).

The second part of the returned pair is a `bool` value (in your case `inserted_happen`) indicating whether insertion succeeded.

In your case, the second `emplace` failed as you have already inserted an element with key equal to 1.

If you want to change the value part of the element, you can just try -

`m[nums[i]] = i;`

Comment: Okay, but what is making it fail? As in when we insert a value that has already been inserted why is it dependent on a boolean? I am bit confused how that is working

Comment: @Wolfy, when you want to insert with some key x, it will check whether some element is already present or not with that key. Based on the presence of the element with same key, it returns you a status whether the insertion was successful. So the bool is the indication that insertion didn't occur.